# How to select specific rows using conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter my data to only Honda CRVs. I noticed that there are a couple types of Honda CRVs and I can't find the condition to select CRVs only.

[image]

Kinda having a hard time here. Don't know what to do

Comment: `df[df['Name'].str.startswith('Honda CR-V')]` - [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look at some examples on [pandas filtering](https://builtin.com/data-science/pandas-filter) and see that we can combine multiple filters using `&` and then we can look at some string methods we can use with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)  to see that we have a `str.startswith`. So we if we combine them into something like this, could work:

`honda_crv_df = df_train_new[(df_train_new['Manufacture'] == "Honda") & (df_train_new['Name'].str.startswith('Honda CR-V'))].sort_values(by="Price", ascending=False)`